# Map .get(), .containsKey() method doesn't work

Tags: java, dictionary

I found out there are many duplicate questions, but I couldn't solve it in my code.

Here is my problem, I have a map,

```
TreeMap<String,Double> relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated = AggregateTwoTreeMaps.Aggregate2nd3rdYearResult(relevantType_Confidence_Map_Sorted, relevantType_Confidence_Third);
// I think the process of making relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated isn't important in this question.
System.out.println(relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated);
{http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing=0.9698529984028573, http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent=0.9679645061134368, http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person=0.9485782773178664}
```

And, I have String variable.

```
String className = "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent";
```

However, get() or containsKey() methods don't work in my current code.

```
System.out.println(relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated.get(className));
null
System.out.println(relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated.containsKey(className));
false
```

For short-term solution, I iterated over entries and get the value that I want, but I want to know what should I modify to use built-in method(get, containsKey)

```
for(Entry<String, Double> e : relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated.entrySet()){
        if(e.getKey().equals(className)){
            System.out.println(e.getValue());
        }
    }
0.9679645061134368
```

Thanks in advance for kind replies.

---

**Supplementary code**

Method Aggregate2nd3rdYearResult

```
public static TreeMap<String, Double> Aggregate2nd3rdYearResult(
        TreeMap<String, Double> relevantType_Confidence_Map_Sorted,
        TreeMap<String, Double> relevantType_Confidence_Third) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TreeMap<String,Double> relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated = new TreeMap<String,Double>();       

    relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated = average(relevantType_Confidence_Map_Sorted, relevantType_Confidence_Third);

    ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated);
    TreeMap<String,Double> relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated_Sorted = new TreeMap<String,Double>(bvc);
    relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated_Sorted.putAll(relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated);

    return relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated_Sorted;
}
```

Method average

```
public static TreeMap<String, Double> average(TreeMap<String, Double> first,
        TreeMap<String, Double> second) {
    // optimization (copy the largest tree map and iterate over the
    // smallest)

    TreeMap<String, Double> result = new TreeMap<String, Double>();
    double threshold = 0.001;

    for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, Double> e : first.entrySet()) {
        Double l = result.get(e.getKey());
        result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue() + (l == null ? 0 : l));
    }
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, Double> e : second.entrySet()) {
        Double l = result.get(e.getKey());
        result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue() + (l == null ? 0 : l));
    }
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, Double> e : result.entrySet()) {
        Double l = result.get(e.getKey());
        result.put(e.getKey(), l/2);
    }


    Iterator it = result.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
    java.util.Map.Entry<String, Double> item = (java.util.Map.Entry<String, Double>) it.next();
       if(item.getValue() < threshold){
           it.remove();
       }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Class ValueComparator

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;

public class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Double> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Double> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }

}
```

Comment: `However, get() or containsKey() methods don't work in my current code.` where is your code ?

Comment: @Babel  ```relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated.get(className);
null
relevantType_Confidence_Map_Aggregated.containsKey(className);
false```

@yshavit  You're right, it returns `false`. I am using eclipse, At first, I thought `>>>` sign makes people understand easier, but it wasn't.

Comment: Where is the code for `AggregateTwoTreeMaps.Aggregate2nd3rdYearResult`, it seems to me that **this** implementation of `Map` has an issue.

Comment: @RC I just edited my post, please check it again.

Answer (score 1):

The `ValueComparator` used by the `TreeMap` is incorrect. It is not only inconsistent with equals but it also violates the requirement that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all x and y. TreeMap with such Comparator can behave incorrectly.

Possible solution is to use `a.compareTo(b)` when `base.get(a) == base.get(b)` (so even keys with same value have some defined order):

```
public int compare(String a, String b) {
    double diff = base.get(a) - base.get(b);
    if (diff > 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (diff < 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```